# Sharepoint page not loading properly for some users

Tags: 2010, ie

Most of the users (*except my team*) are not able to load our sharepoint site. They do have access but all the view is broken. This started 2 days back (*without any change from my end*) before which everything was working fine.

[image]

### MORE INFO:

1. Only our team (5 members) can view it correctly. Rest all get this broken page.
2. Deleted Cookies, Cache & Temp files for the effected users (Not resolved)
3. Added the website in Compatibility View Settings (Not resolved)
4. Tried changing the permission to 'Contribute' for those users (Not resolved)
5. Tried adding a new user to our Teams group today (just to check), but even he is getting this incorrect page
6. Tried adding a new user (who is not part of any group) in Admin group, still he is getting the same incorrect page
7. Our team use (IE8 & IE11) and there is no problem loading the pages for us, it is only other groups & new people added to the site
8. This site is on SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem arises when you set an unpublished master page from Site Settings. The 5 of you must be SCA. Do the below:

- Check in the master page
- Approve it
- Publish

Comment: When  I go into Site Settings - > Master Page -> check default.master, the Approve & Publish options are disabled.

Comment: Did you try setting up a different masterpage ?